# How to run return to login file and run jQuery function from PHP if else statement

Tags: php

I have following PHP if/else statement - how can I tell it to go back to login.php and run jQuery function?

```
if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {

            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'] = $member['login'];
            session_write_close();

            header("location: ../index.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            $error = true;
                    // go back to login.php and run jQuery function

            }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
            // // or go back to login.php and run different jQuery function


    }
```

Comment: You should call this with AJAX from login.php, and then call your jQuery functions in the callback.

Comment: You question is a bit vague... are you calling this script through Ajax?

Comment: @Felix - let me past in login.php file.

Comment: @Felis - here is my login.php file http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/jxC2L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
header('Location: login.php?message=query_failed');
```

or

```
header('Location: login.php?message=login_failed');
```

and on your `login.php` inside your `javascript tags`:

you can use `php` for:

```
<?php if($_GET['message'] == 'query_failed'):  ?>

jquery_query_failed_function();

<?php elseif($_GET['message'] == 'login_failed'):  ?>

jquery_login_failed_function();

<?php endif; ?>
```

so Continuing from your `else` statement: it should be:

continuing from your else statement:

```
else {
        $error = true;
        header('Location: login.php?message=login_failed');

        }
}else {

    header('Location: login.php?message=query_failed');
    die("Query failed");
        // // or go back to login.php and run different jQuery function


}
```

Comment: Is this name fixed or can I call it anythig? `jquery_query_failed_function`

Comment: you can call any of your jquery or javascript function :) this is just for simplifying the concept!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/Cghvp/ - FireBug is saying that `$('p.error').LoginMissing(); is undefind`. Why?

Comment: in the mean time, I had just corrected something in `$_GET` to `$_GET['message']` and somethings in `if-elseif-endif` syntax, please correct them appropriately

Comment: Also why dont you use `$.loginFailed();` instead of $('_p.error_').loginFailed();

Comment: @linuxease - ok, so php if/else is working correctly (can see it in the URL) - but function on login page is never fired off. Why?

Comment: if you are using those jquery functions without `('p.error')`, this seems to work on my side!

Comment: Delete those but still nothing, URL as follow: `http://localhost/form/login-form.php?message=login_failed` / `http://localhost/form/login-form.php?message=login_missing` and JS here: ** http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/fsQva/**

Comment: use `$.loginFailed();` and `$.LoginMissing();` appropriately as you have created these as your javascript functions! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: ../login.php?error_code=1");
header("Location: ../login.php?error_code=2");
```

Based on the error code you would execute a different function, that's if you wanna use redirects.